# what is the shortest allowable time control for a FIDE rated standard tournament game?

Tags: fide, time-control

My chess club wants to host a FIDE tournament in a couple of months with 3 FIDE rated games in one day.

What is the shortest allowed time control for FIDE rated standard tournament games so we can fit in all 3 games on one day?  Thanks!

Best,
Richard

Answer (score 6):

According to the [FIDE Rating Regulations](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=197&view=article), it depends on the player ratings:

> 1.1 For a game to be rated each player must have the following minimum periods in which to complete all the moves, assuming the game lasts 60 moves.
>   Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating 2200 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 120 minutes.
>   Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating 1600 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 90 minutes.
>   Where both of the players in the game are rated below 1600, each player must have a minimum of 60 minutes.
>
> 1.2 Where a certain number of moves is specified in the first time control, it shall be 40 moves.